# Zf2 Flashmessenger in multiple layouts

Tags: layout, zend-framework2

I've got some issue with render flashmessenger in multiple layouts with ZfcTwitterBootstrap module.
In one module layout I render messege like this:

```
    <div class="container">
        <?php echo $this->ztbFlashMessenger()->render(); ?>
    </div>
```

But if I render flashmessenger in another layout it doesn't get rendered. If I disable flashmessenger in first module I got rendered in another.
Is there a way to render it in all layouts ?
Thanks in advance for some answers and tips.

Comment: you are using it in the wrong way, the whole point in FLASH messages is they are used once and thrown away.

Comment: ok.. so there's no way to render it in layout ?
if I redirect from one module to another the message doesn't getting render.

Answer (score 1):

you have many other solutions found on web. Maybe you could find the reason of the problem.

- https://gist.github.com/gpeltink/3693361
- http://samminds.com/2012/08/flashmessenger-in-zend-framework-2/

Otherwise I have developed an useful module. Inside it exists an extended flash messenger, you can add to your layout.

- https://github.com/remithomas/rt-extends
- https://github.com/remithomas/rt-extends/wiki/Create-notifications-with-Flash-messenger-and-pnotify

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. anyway, i render with ZfcTwitterBootstrap in layout by:
                echo $this->ztbFlashMessenger('error');
                echo $this->ztbFlashMessenger()->render('info');
                echo $this->ztbFlashMessenger()->render('success');
                echo $this->ztbFlashMessenger()->render('default');
            ?>
and it works in multiple modules layouts.

Comment: I've change the location of layout to application_root (so I got one layout for all modules) and then simple 
echo $this->ztbFlashMessenger()->render(); works fine.